# Uniform Grid like Table in RDLC

Tags: .net, reportviewer, rdlc

I have a report in which I like to display information from one table in the following way

```
-----------------------------
- Row1 - Row2 - Row3 - Row4 -
- Row5 - Row6 - Row7 - Row8 -
- Row9 -      -      -      -
-----------------------------
```

And so on. In WPF, I could easily display this way using a uniformgrid with 4 columns. Is there any way to do this in a RDLC report?

I figure I could rework the data in my query so that instead of having one row I actually have 4 and fill it accordingly, but I wonder if there is a more elegant way to do so?

Comment: You can use .Columns property of your Report but it doesn't works exactly as you want: it fills a column with data and the move to the next.

Comment: You could use matrix (depending on complexity of Row<n> of course, not enough information to know for sure), but would have to add some criteria for row grouping - some "matrix Row Number".

Comment: As far as I know, Matrix are pretty much tablix made for pivot table. I don't see how this would work. Like I mentionnend, I guess I could rework the data to make it work, but I wondered if there was another way